# Function 'xsltParseStylesheetDoc' not found in [libxml2.so]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, nokogiri, libxml2

This error comes up in Redhat Enterprise Linux Server 5.4 - 64 bit.

Linux rhl-64-tibbr5 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

There is also this error in the stack trace.

uninitialized constant Nokogiri::VERSION_INFO

More version details:

jruby-1.4.0RC1
ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a few hours on this issue, we realized we didn't need nokogiri in our application. So we got it rid of it and these errors disappeared.

Note: these errors show up only on a 64 bit Linux machine ( like RHEL, Oracle Linux etc.,). We didn't see any errors with 32-bit operating systems ( both Win and Linux)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar errors when using Nokogiri with JRuby 1.4.0 (and higher). What turned out to be the problem was that the machine was 64-bit but the JRE that JRuby ended up using was 32-bit. Ensuring that JRuby was run using a 64-bit JRE on a 64-bit machine solved the issues for me.

Some specifics in this [blog post](http://www.wikyblog.com/AmanKing/Nokogiri%2C_JRuby%2C_64-bit_vs_32-bit_JRE).